# Excel 2019 data validation list valid formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I am trying to create a formula for a drop down list based on a conditional format, where only the cells in G column will be shown if in the column before (the F one) in the same row the cell has some predefined value (cell K4).

When running the formula on a cell and if i press F9 it will the following result (check pic as well)

```
={"Doc";"Doc";"Doc";"rec 3";"Doc";"Doc";"Doc";"Doc";"Doc";"rec 9";"rec 10";"rec 11";"rec 12"}
```

However when i place such formula in the Data Validation under the option list it will show only the first result.
The Idea is to create such dropdown with the use of a direct approach and not with the use of third cells where i will have the place the result on them.

This is the formula

```
=OFFSET(F1,IF( ((F2:F14=K4))*ROW(F2:F14) = 0, 0,( ((F2:F14=K4))*ROW(F2:F14))-1),1)
```

I have try as well placing the INDIRECT formula on it but it gives an error... Not sure what else i can do...

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to achieve? What is the logic? Looks to me that the formula is overly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Validation formulas can only process very simple functions. For something more complex, set up the formula in a range name formula and then use the range name in the data validation setup.

Comment: ohh ... i see and there is no way around that them... Was trying to avoid that, that why i said a more direct approach. Thanks. Will do that them...

Comment: Why do you want to "avoid" named ranges? It's like "avoiding" the clutch in a manual drive car.

Comment: well to  have a more clean sheet or in this particular case to avoid doing hidden cells to print and/or convert the final result to pdf (export)

Comment: Named ranges are not showing on any sheet. Did you understand what I'm suggesting? Even if there was a need for helper cells, they could be on a separate sheet. Even if you need to print to PDF, you could print just the one, clean sheet. Please try to follow suggestions. Sometimes, if your approach is not working, you will actually have to change things in order to make them work.

Comment: i know that and i will follow your suggestion... just said was trying to avoid it... guess it's not possible so...